# Problem in Mesh Rotation around another Mesh of imported FBX model in Three.js

Tags: three.js, rotation, pivot, axis, mesh

For the learning purposes, I downloaded a layalty-free FBX model from a website, which happens to be a helicopter. I want to emulate the rotation of the helicopter blades programmatically in Three.js. I imported the moded successfully by means of FBXLoader, without any problem. I checked its meshes in Blender, and it has more than fifty meshes. I pinpointed the blades' meshes and wrote this in the load() function:

```
      pivotPoint = new THREE.Object3D();
      const loader = new THREE.FBXLoader();
      group = new THREE.Object3D();

  loader.load(
    'Apache.fbx',
     object => {
          scene.add(object);

         const twentyFive = scene.getObjectByName('Mesh25'); //This is the shaft which the blades should rotate around
         console.log(twentyFive); //x: 685.594482421875, y: 136.4067840576172, z: -501.9534606933594
         twentyFive.add(pivotPoint);

         const twentyEight = scene.getObjectByName('Mesh28');//These four are the blades
         const twentyNine = scene.getObjectByName('Mesh29');
         const twentySeven = scene.getObjectByName('Mesh27');
         const twentySix = scene.getObjectByName('Mesh26');

         group.add(twentyEight);
         group.add(twentyNine);
         group.add(twentySeven);
         group.add(twentySix);

         pivotPoint.add(group);
         scene.add(pivotPoint);
         scene.add(twentyFive);

      },
        progress => ...,
        error => ...
       );
```

and the following in the loop render function:

```
pivotPoint.rotation.y += 0.01;
```

However, either the four blades disappear once I add the nesting Object3Ds or upon changing the code into the above version with numerous mutations, the four blades would strangely rotate around some other point in sky, apart from the fuselage, while the awe-stricken pilot watches the catastrophe and amazed by the aforementioned code, as if the helicopter is about to crash any second!
I tried many changes to the code. Basically I had once used the Object3D parenting for some light sources on another scene, but have no idea what's the issue now. Besides, the rotation of the blades around Mesh25 (my wished pivot) is around a big circle with no contacts with the fuselage, although all four are beautifully revolve around their center of mass.
I really appreciate any help, as I really need to learn to wrestle with similar imported models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`attach`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.attach) instead of `add` in the appropriate places.

```
         const twentyFive = scene.getObjectByName('Mesh25');

         // add the pivot and group first so they are in the scene
         pivotPoint.add(group);
         twentyFive.add(pivotPoint);

         const twentyEight = scene.getObjectByName('Mesh28');
         const twentyNine = scene.getObjectByName('Mesh29');
         const twentySeven = scene.getObjectByName('Mesh27');
         const twentySix = scene.getObjectByName('Mesh26');

         // use attach to move something in the scene hierarchy without
         // changing its position
         group.attach(twentyEight);
         group.attach(twentyNine);
         group.attach(twentySeven);
         group.attach(twentySix);
```

This assumes the model is created correctly in the first place and that the the shaft's position `Mesh25` is in the center of the shaft.

Note: If the shaft's origin is in the correct position and the blades are already children of the shaft you can just rotate the shaft.

Comment: Thank you very much gman. I replaced the `add` methods with `attach` and saw no change in the behavior. However, after carefully testing your warning about the model being created correctly, I suspected whether the model is in good shape. Technically, no matter how I was changing the code and even using Quaternions and many other witchcrafts, any mesh would spin around a fixed place in space under the model. So I replaced my model and changed my loading code entirely, and even incorporated more extended nested hierarchy, and the new helicopter works like a charm using `attach` method.